# Spring Cloud Stream - First Kafka messages get error "Dispatcher has no subscribers"

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

My app successfully sends Kafka messages, but only after Kafka is initialized. Before that i get the error "Dispatcher has no subscribers". How do i wait for subscribers to finish being registered for channels?

Here's a trace of the order of events (timing in second.ms):

- 17.165 SenderClass created
- 17.816 initialization class, @PostConstruct starts PollingTask
- 24.781 PollingTask sends first Kafka message
- 24.816 First error: "Dispatcher has no subscribers"
- 25.778 Registering MessageChannel my-channel
- still seeing Dispatcher errors
- 27.067 Channel my-channel' has 1 subscriber
- No more errors after this, messages send fine

i'm not sure how to approach this. Wild guesses have included:

1. Place sending code in @PostConstruct
2. Add @AutoConfigureBefore(BindingServiceConfiguration.class) to Sender
3. Add @AutoConfigureAfter(BindingServiceConfiguration.class) to SenderClass
4. Add @AutoConfigureBefore(BindingServiceConfiguration.class) to Main
5. Place @DependsOn({"EnableBindingClass"}) on Task
6. Place @DependsOn({"ApplicationLifeCycle"}) on SchedulerClass, where ApplicationLifeCycle is a class that does nothing but
   implements SmartLifecycle with getPhase returning MAX_INT
7. Making sure ComponentScan is on for whole package (a suggestion from other SO threads)
8. Various combinations of the above

Created a new app, made it as simple as i could:

```java
public interface Source {
  @Output(channelName)
  MessageChannel outboundChannel();
}
```

```java
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@Component
public class Sender {
  @Autowired
  private Source source;

  public boolean send(SomeObject object) {
    return source.outboundChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(object).build());
  }
```

```java
@Service
public class Scheduler {
  @Autowired
  Sender sender;
  @Autowired
  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize() {
    taskScheduler.schedule(new PollingTask(), nextTime);
  }

  private class PollingTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      List<SomeObject> objects = getDummyData();
      for(SomeObject object : objects)
      {
        sender.send(interval);
      }

      Instant nextTime = Instant.now().plusMillis(1_000L);
      try {
        taskScheduler.schedule(new PollingTask(), nextTime);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
      }
    }
}
```

**Edit to add Solution**

It works now! In my scheduler that starts the things that send the messages i switched from starting things in @PostConstruct to SmartLifecycle::start().

```java
@Service
public class Scheduler implements SmartLifecycle {
  @Autowired
  Sender sender;
  @Autowired
  ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler;

  @Override
  public void start() {
    taskScheduler.schedule(new PollingTask(), nextTime);
  }

  private class PollingTask implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      List<SomeObject> objects = getDummyData();
      for(SomeObject object : objects)
      {
        sender.send(interval);
      }

      Instant nextTime = Instant.now().plusMillis(1_000L);
      try {
        taskScheduler.schedule(new PollingTask(), nextTime);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PostConstruct is too early to send messages; the context is still being built.. Implememt SmartLifecycle, put the bean in a high phase (Integer.MAX_VALUE) and do the sends in start().

Or do the sends in an ApplicationRunner.

Comment: Sorry, i'm too newb to understand. i have a SmartLifeCycle object (option 6 above). Not sure what to put in it so it's just empty, phase=max int. It fires long before the context is ready. You mention putting the bean in it. Not sure how that works. i have no explicit beans and no explicit Kafka classes. i have the Sender component with EnableBinding, the interface with Output and the PollingTask service that calls Sender. Is it one of those?

Comment: You need to show where you are calliing `reportData()` from. Edit the question; don't add it as a comment; it won't render well.

Comment: Edited the question to show more complete code. Simplified it - equivalent of `reportData()` is now in internal class `PollingTask`'s run() method.

Comment: Seems you ignored my advice; DON'T start the scheduled task in `@PostConstruct` - it's too early to start messagin activity. Change `Scheduler` to implement `SmartLifecyle` (late phase) and start the scheduler in `start()`.

Comment: i didn't ignore your advice, i just didn't know how to implement it :) Wasn't sure which object should have SmartLifecycle but thanks to your last comment, now i know. i've tested and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Is the High Phase part necessary? i did a few runs without it and it still worked.

Comment: You might get lucky, but the bindings are started quite late, in phase `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000` so it should really be later than that, to avoid any race conditions.

Comment: Actually no, sorry, that's the inbound  bindings; the outbound bindings are started in an early phase `Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1000` so anything later will be ok (e.g. 0). We make sure all inbound bindings are bound after the outbound.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem in Webflux + Spring Cloud Stream functional style. Spring Cloud Function in 2022 is the preferred way. ​

My hypothesis after a lot of debugging was that beans were not created in right order. The bean was probably not registered in spring-cloud-stream's dispatchers before kafka message processing started. similar to what @gary mentioned.

So I added `@Order(1)` before my consumer beans. Hoping that this bean would be created before it is dispatcher-registrations starts.

```java
   ​@Bean
   ​@Order(1)
   ​public Function<Flux<Message<Pojo>>, Mono<Void>> pojoConsumer() {
```

This seems to fix my issue for now.